# Can I have multiple relationship between 2 entities?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing a problem during ER diagram .
I have come to a situation where I need to show multiple relations between 2 entities, as well as I need to show relation between attribute and entity...
I know it is illegal .
But can I somehow achieve this ?

Comment: You need to be more specific than that

Comment: Why do you think relationships are "illegal"?  Please elaborate on what you're trying to describe.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create new parent table with both entity (parent and child entity).

new ENTITY_TABLE --> RELATION - relation is attributte of entity too

new ENTITY_TABLE --> ATTRIBUTE
[image]